# How to make a button to have some active or inactive effect when a menu is being displayed and hidden in flutter (using "showMenu" )

Tags: flutter, button, flutter-layout, flutter-web

1. I am using showMenu() function to create and render a menu when onTap() on a certain ListTile widget. So, How to make the ListTile show in an active/inactive state (using some background colour) when the menu is active and vice versa.
2. PS. I am able to achieve active state when the list tile is clicked using onTap() but unable to achieve the inactive state as I am unable to find a way of reverting the `List Tile background colour because there is no toggle/function when the pop-up menu from show menu is closed.
3. Please check the below images to get more clarity on the issue.

inactive state
[image: inactive state]

active and menu open
[image: active and menu open]

menu closed but colour is still in effect

[image: menu closed but colour is still in effect]

```
    // List to maintain active states (item will be pushed to list on onTap() function)
    List sideOptions = [];

    // function to return color w.r.t if statements
    Color changeBackground(bool isHovered, String sideOption) {
    print(currentRoute);
    if ((isHovered || (currentRoute == "/$sideOption")) ||
        sideOptions.contains(sideOption)) {
      return global_styles.blueShade;
    } else {
      return Colors.transparent;
    }
  }
    // ListTile wrapped in a container
    // OnHoverIcon() is a function i wrote to capture hover events if any
    // ListTile onTap() function


    _buildPopUpMenuButton(
      String title, String iconString, List<PopupMenuEntry> subItems) {
        child: OnHoverIcon(builder: (isHovered) {
            return Container(
              height: 55,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: changeBackground(isHovered, title),
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(8.0),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(8.0),
                ),
              ),
                  child: ListTile(
                    onTap: () => {
                      sideOptions.add(title),
                      if (!_isDropdownOpen)
                        {_controller.forward(), _isDropdownOpen = true}
                      else
                        {
                          _controller.reverse(),
                          _isDropdownOpen = false,
                        },
                      // _isDropdownOpen = true,
                      showMenu(
                          context: context,
                          position: getSizeandPosition(),
                          items: subItems)
                    },
                    leading: Image.asset(
                      iconString,
                      color: changeIconColors(isHovered, title),
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      title,
                      style: sideNavItems(isHovered, title),
                    ),
                    trailing: title != "Settings"
                        ? RotationTransition(
                            turns: _rotationAnimation,
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.keyboard_arrow_up,
                              color: changeIconColors(isHovered, title),
                            ),
                          )
                        : null,
                  ),
            );
          }
        );
      }
}`
```

Comment: Can you include sample code-snippet ?

Comment: I have updated the question the code regarding that list-tile and color changing function . Please take a look .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`showMenu()` returns a `Future` that ends when the menu is popped. So, you can place an `await` before it and it'll continue to the next line when the menu is popped.

Like this:

```dart
void onTap() async {
  // Set the tile as active (changes the color to blue)
  setState(() {
    isActive = true;
  });

  // Show menu and wait for it to pop.
  await showMenu(
    /* ... */
  );

  // Menu is popped. Set the tile as inactive and return to the default color.
  setState(() {
    isActive = false;
  });
}
```

Edit: It's best to extract the button to its own `StatefulWidget` so `setState()` will update just the button instead of the whole page.

---

If this doesn't work with your code. Maybe place a stateful widget in the menu and use `dispose()` to detect when it's no longer active and trigger the inactivation method.

Comment: Thanks @Elfor used "await" as you suggested and also the buttons are separate StatefulWidgets.